# Java while loop won't break

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm writing a simple game that uses a loop `while(game = true)`.

I set `game = false` in the code during the loop. When I run the game, it stops at that point but does not terminate.

However, if I use `break` instead at the same spot the program terminates. Why can't I use `game = false`?

Comment: Should be `while(game == true)` or even better `while(game)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression

```
game = true
```

assigns `true` to`game` and the result of this expression is always true.

What you intended as to test if the previous value of `game` was true

```
while(game == true)
```

or much simpler

```
while(game)
```

Usually you give it a better name like

```
while(running) {
```

Comment: Straight forward, and accurate. Nice one. +1

Answer (score -4):

at the end of the while loop use

```
while (game = true)
*whatever happens when the game = true*
break();
```

if that doesn't work try something like this

```
while game = (true);
while (game == true) {
*whatever happens in game loop*
}
```

make sure somewhere before you start your game loop, you have something telling the code when to make game = false. If you don't the game will run forever without ever changing back to false.

Comment: See Peter's answer: your code examples are wrong. Also, what does this mean: "make sure somewhere before you start your game loop, you have something telling the code when to make game = false"?

Comment: if you say: if running {game = true} and there's nothing to stop the game from being true, then no matter what you code, the game runs endlessly as true.

Comment: It's the "before you start your game loop" that is confusing.

Comment: Your first code example is just wrong completely. `break` is a keyword, not a method like `break()`.